# ASP membership services is ALWAYS creating two accounts

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-membership

I am using the ASP membership services to create and manage users. I notice that on user account registration everything works fine... Until I call Roles.AddUserToRole, and suddenly I get a second user account created in the aspnet_users table. Can someone explain this? I am quite certain that I should only ever have one user account in the database per registered user...

Comment: Could you provide some more information?  How and when are these users being created?  What does the data in the aspnet_users table look like for each user?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Roles and membership are separate concerns, e.g. do not depend on one another, so the multiple records in aspnet_Users do indicate that you may want to examine your configuration and  ensure that your membership and roleManager elements either:

1. both have NO `applicationName` defined (default '/') or
2. both have the SAME `applicationName` defined

Answer (score 1):

http://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/archive/2010/01/09/asp-net-mebership-creates-two-users-in-aspnet-users-table.aspx